# Nginx static media, and problems with trailing slashes

Tags: nginx

Sigh... just when I thought I had figured out all the issues with trailing slashes in URLs for `Django` - and I start working with `nginx`...

So I'm configuring `nginx` to serve static media, and failing repeatedly - despite my config looking *exactly* like all the other static-media questions on SO. Eventually I realize that it's not the `nginx` config, but my HTML file, which includes a trailing slash on the .css file:

```
# hello.html (invalid)
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/css/hello.css/" type="text/css" />
# resulting log error
[error] 27705#0: "/home/www/static/css/hello.css/index.html" is not found 
request: "GET /media/css/hello.css/ HTTP/1.1"
# hello.html (valid)
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/css/hello.css" type="text/css" />
```

By removing the trailing slash on the filename, it worked fine. But *why*? Shouldn't URLs end in trailing slashes?

I recently went through all my `Django` templates, adding slashes to every media file. Do I have to *remove* them all, or is there some configuration option in `nginx` that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the slash in the request will make most servers assume that you want the hello.css folder in the css folder. Obviously, that's going to confuse it.

> Shouldn't URLs end in trailing
>   slashes?

Nope. Do a view-source for this page, or almost any other.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
```

See? No trailing slash.